# Word for "motion in slowly expanding" circles?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means to circle outward from a center point, with each circle getting a little larger than the previous, as would be used by a search party, for example.

> "The helicopter flew in ______ circles as we peered down toward the trees."
>
> "Start there, and [walk (or any motion) in] ______ [circles] until you find a table with your name on it."

A single word for the whole thing would also be acceptable.

I found [this](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/circumnutation) word "circumnutation," but the main meaning of that word seems specific to plants, and the directly relevant version of the word is marked as not accepted and might not be standard. It's also specifically referring to ripples in water, which is not what I'm looking for. I also think the word I'm looking for is something I've encountered in the past, just can't remember at the moment.

Comment: Do you mean *spiral*?

Comment: "The helicopter flew in spiral circles?" No. I'm thinking of circles that get wider about when you get to the point at which you started. I'm not sure if that's technically a spiral or not, but either way, the question stands.

Comment: I would expand on @michael.hor257k's suggestion to make it "_The helicopter **spiraled outward** as we peered down toward the trees._"  Although, now reading that, it might get read as "spiraled out of control" if someone weren't paying close attention.

Comment: I didn't say "spiral circles", I said "spiral", which is both a noun and a verb as well as an adjective. If you want to describe circles, then perhaps "widening" or "ever-widening" might suit.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn That's how I read it, even paying attention. I'd probably figure out that it wasn't actually out of control when, a paragraph or two later, they still hadn't crashed and didn't seem worried. Then I would check back two paragraphs and wonder why the author used that word. So yeah, more specific application, but still not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @michael.hor257k the second definition of spiral is *show a continuous and dramatic increase*, which is much looser than what the OP thinks

Comment: @marcellothearcane My dictionary defines it as *winding in a continuous and gradually widening (or tightening) curve* - which is **exactly** what OP describes.

Comment: @michael.hor257k -- I think "flew in a spiral" could work, although it lacks the horizontal aspect (which folks would eventually figure out).  I do like your suggestion of "ever-widening circles"; I think that has a nice ring to it, even if it isn't technically correct from a physics/geometry point of view (I'm not sure it isn't, btw.)

Comment: @RogerSinasohn If a radius of a circle can change over time, then the circle can widen - in geometry as well as in plain language.

Comment: @michael.hor257k -- Yeah, I see your point, which goes with the suggestion of concentric.  In my mind, however, _concentric_ and _spiral_ are two different things.  But that's probably because I'm an idiot. 8^)

Comment: If I give you concentric circles you can count them; If I give you a spiral you can't so easily count the circles, as they are less distinct.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn Only a subatomic particle can fly in concentric circles by performing a quantum jump from one circle to another. A helicopter can only fly along the path of a spiral (or helix).

Comment: @michael.hor257k a helicopter can fly along concentric circles if it is allowed to switch to the next one once it finishes a circuit

Comment: @Menasheh I would argue that it is impossible to count the circles in a spiral because there aren't any. A circle is a closed shape and concentric circles are nested (as you can tell, I'm no geometer) closed shapes. A spiral, however, is an open shape that is not circular although it is often described as such.

Answer (score 9):

Consider:

> The helicopter flew in ***[ever-widening](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/widen)*** circles as we peered down
>   toward the trees.

Comment: +1, or even just *widening* on its own.

Answer (score 1):

There's **emanate**:

> (of something abstract but perceptible) to issue or spread out from (a source).

Source: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/emanate)

Or maybe the circles are **concentric**:

> of or denoting circles, arcs, or other shapes that share the same center, the larger often completely surrounding the smaller.

Source: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/concentric)

Comment: I always thought of concentric as the circular version of parallel -- that is, the circles don't touch, much like a target.  I think OP is looking for something more spiral-ish.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn yes, they are. but the OP didn't seem to like 'spiral'. I think they're wanting 'go round in a circle then go a bit wider, then do a circle, etc...'

Comment: @RogerSinasohn: The circles don't just "not touch", they also share the same center (hence "con"-"centric"). [It's possible to draw circles that do not touch yet not share the same center](http://study.com/cimages/multimages/16/drawingnonconcentriccircles.png). This is a bit different for lines, as they are infinitely long, and therefore not touching can only be achieved by them being exactly parallel.

Answer (score 0):

How about **chocleate**?

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/cochleate) gives the medical definition: having the form of a snail shell

For fun, here's a [Mental Floss](http://mentalfloss.com/article/56927/18-fancy-words-specific-shapes) article titled "18 Fancy Words for Specific Shapes" that includes **chocleate**.

Comment: Not my down-vote on this answer, but does *chocleate* relate to the 1D path embedded in 3D space, or to the 3D spiral-shell shape? By the way, it often helps to include a relevant excerpt when you include links in answers - pages sometimes get edited or deleted etc.

Answer (score 0):

> The helicopter flew in **spirals** as we peered down toward the
>   trees.

is the most natural wording in US English.

> Start there, and walk in **spirals** until you find a table with your
>   name on it.

Or (a little less idiomatic):

> Start there, and **spiral** until you find a table with your
>   name on it.

Answer (score -3):

What about **centrifugal**?

Centrifugal means "moving or tending to move away from a center".

> "The helicopter flew in a **centrifugal** spiral as we peered down..."

or

> "The helicopter flew in **centrifugal** circles as we peered down..."

It accurately describes what you're trying to communicate and it isn't so obscure a word that it will confuse or alienate your readers.

Comment: Why the downvote?